# I want to send mail through form data. I want the receiver to be fixed and sender only changes.How can I achieve this?

Tags: python, django

This is the `models.py`. The email field is the sender with the `password` and receiver is `email1`.

```
class ContactModel(models.Model):
    fullname = models.CharField(max_length=20,null=True,blank=True)
    email=models.EmailField(null=True,blank=True)
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    email1=models.EmailField(null=True,blank=True)
    subject=models.CharField(max_length=30,null=True,blank=True)
    message=models.TextField(max_length=200)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=COLOR_CHOICES, default='green')
```

This is my `views.py` file.

```
def contact_page(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            fullname =form.cleaned_data.get("fullname")
            email =form.cleaned_data.get(settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER)
            password=form.cleaned_data.get(settings.EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD)
            subject =form.cleaned_data.get("subject")
            model_instance = form.save(commit=False)
            fullname = request.POST.get('fullname', '')
            email1 = request.POST.get('email1', '')
            message = request.POST.get('message', '')
            color = request.POST.get('color', '')
            # Email the profile with the
            # contact information
            template = get_template('contact_template.txt')
            context = {
                        'fullname': fullname,
                        'email': email,
                        'message': message,
                        'color':color,
                        'email1': email1,
                    }
            message = template.render(context)

            email = EmailMessage("Test Mail",message,settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,[email1], headers = {'Reply-To': email1 } )
            email.send()
            model_instance.save()
            return render(request,'form/success.html')
    else:
        form = ContactForm()
    return render(request, "contact_page.html", {'form': form})
```

Please help me only one receiver and sender changes. I will be thankful for your help.
Trying to retrieve the form data through mail sending this to mail.

Comment: basically you want to send multiple mails to one person? why?

Comment: It's a contact form so whenever someone submit the form the data should go through mail to a specific user(receiver) in this case.

Comment: I just want the sender's mail and password in  field can be used as EMAIL_HOST_USER and EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD in settings.py file . Can it be possible?

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking for is the ability to spoof email addresses -- to send mail from your account on your server, and make it look as if it came from someone else.

This is a bad idea -- spoofing email addresses will get you quickly blacklisted as a suspected spammer or hacker, and many systems will reject such emails automatically.

Instead, just let the email come from the address you're actually using, and in the body of the message put the address of the person the reply should go to.

Comment: As well as putting the address in the body, you can set a reply-to header.